# CSS disable text selection

Tags: css

Currently, I have put this in the body tag to disable text selections:

```
body {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

However, my `input` and `textarea` boxes are now unselectable. How can I only make these input elements selectable and the rest unselectable?

Comment: I'm able to select `input` and `textarea` elements: http://jsfiddle.net/Smy26/

Comment: Looks like webkit allows selection on those elements, but moz doesn't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS rule to disable text selection highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

Comment: I know that this is an old question, but it would be nice to share in the question, why there was the need to deny text selection in the whole body as default. That could be useful to share, since most answers are just guessing your intentions. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 224, accepted):

Don't apply these properties to the whole body. Move them to a class and apply that class to the elements you want to disable select:

```
.disable-select {
  -webkit-user-select: none;  
  -moz-user-select: none;    
  -ms-user-select: none;      
  user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 42):

You could also disable user select on all elements:

```
* {
    -webkit-touch-callout:none;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -ms-user-select:none;
    user-select:none;
}
```

And than enable it on the elements you do want the user to be able to select:

```
input, textarea /*.contenteditable?*/ {
    -webkit-touch-callout:default;
    -webkit-user-select:text;
    -moz-user-select:text;
    -ms-user-select:text;
    user-select:text;
}
```

Comment: For full browser support you should add following attributes to your <body> or <div> element: unselectable="yes" onselectstart="return false" onmousedown="return false"   /*use with care, the last attribute can AFFECT EXISTING FUNCTOIONALITY*/

Answer (score 13):

Just wanted to summarize everything:

```
.unselectable {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

<div class="unselectable" unselectable="yes" onselectstart="return false;"/>
```

Comment: Old versions of Firefox could require adding one more attribute to HTML: onmousedown="return false"

Answer (score 2):

Use a wild card selector `*` for this purpose.

```
#div * { /* Narrowing, to specific elements, like  input, textarea is PREFFERED */
 -webkit-user-select: none;  
  -moz-user-select: none;    
  -ms-user-select: none;      
  user-select: none;
}
```

Now, every element inside a div with id `div` will have no selection.

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Smy26/5/)

Answer (score 2):

```
::selection,::moz-selection {color:currentColor;background:transparent}
```

Comment: As stated here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_selection.asp.
This is not part of any CSS specification so far, and Firefox requires -moz-.
So the correct should be: 
::-moz-selection {color:currentColor;background:transparent}
::selection {color:currentColor;background:transparent}

Comment: @Vladislav Good point about the moz prefix. Honestly tho, don't trust w3schools. Its such a terrible source. MDN gives the *actual* browser compatibility versions and notes that ::selection was removed from the CSS draft, BUT was added back: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection . Another note, firefox is ready to remove the need for the prefix: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=509958

Answer (score 2):

you can disable all selection

```
.disable-all{-webkit-touch-callout: none;  -webkit-user-select: none;-khtml-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;}
```

now you can enable input and text-area enable

```
input, textarea{
-webkit-touch-callout:default;
-webkit-user-select:text;
-khtml-user-select: text;
-moz-user-select:text;
-ms-user-select:text;
user-select:text;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Someth Victory, you need to add a specific class to some elements you want to be unselectable.

Also, you may add this class in specific cases using javascript. Example here [Making content unselectable with help of CSS](http://web.archive.org/web/20120628134117/http://starikovs.com/2011/01/29/css-unselectable/).

Answer (score 0):

Disable selection everywhere

```
input, textarea ,*[contenteditable=true] {
  -webkit-touch-callout:default;
  -webkit-user-select:text;
  -moz-user-select:text;
  -ms-user-select:text;
  user-select:text;
   }
```

IE7

```
 <BODY oncontextmenu="return false" onselectstart="return false" ondragstart="return false">
```