# The three line menu icon - highlight goes crazy

Tags: jquery, html, css

On the website, when I click on the menu button repeatedly, the menu and the navigation highlights completely. On my actual project (not the codepen), this makes the whole hero image + navigation + landing page highlight when you click it in fast progression.

Is there a way to stop the highlight? This can cause some usability issues.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEroxj

```
<div class = "mobile-nav-button">&#9776;</div>
```

problem mostly lies with this div right here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809995/css-disable-text-selection